# Differences in TNSNAMES and LISTENER files

Tags: listener, oracle12c, tnsnames

I have installed Oracle on two different azure virtual machines and between the installation the version of oracle 12C has changed SE1 to SE2 and despite setting up both machines in the same to the best of my knowledge the TNSNAMES.ORA differs between environments

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host-live.f10.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EMMA)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

On my test server which I believed to have set up in a similar manner the TNSNAMES.ORA file is as follows:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_EMMATEST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


DBTEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host-test.f7.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EMMATEST)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

I am unsure as to why the test server has an additional listener in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. If I look further at the LISTENER.ORA file found on each environment they are as follows:

LIVE:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_DB =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

DB =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host-live.f10.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

TEST:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DBTEST =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host-test.f7.cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_DBTEST = D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log
```

I am relatively knew to Oracle and would be very grateful if someone could assist me in helping to discover where I have gone wrong in setting up the test environment.